# ViewPager work around for onClick event

Tags: android, events, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` as a `ListView` header , now every thing is working well , what i want to do next , is to make the user eligible to move between pages in the `ViewPager` , and to be able to click on the Page so i can fire a new `Activity`. i tried `setOnClickListener` on the `ViewPager` but it fired when i want to move between pages . any work around for this ???

Edit: I dont want to `setOnClickListener` in any view in the ViewPager. like a `Button` .

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? You want to start a new activity onClick of View pager? There must be some component in the view pager page that you want to be clickable right?

Comment: i want the whole page to be clickable . so in nutshell i want to know if the user if fling (" move between pages in viewpager") or click on it .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `onClickListener` to the view (Maybe a button) in your view pager `adapter` and handle the click in the adapter.

**EDIT**
You could bettter use a ViewFlipper for that kind of functionality.

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {
            //Single Tap
            return false;
        };

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > REL_SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;

                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
                    vf.setInAnimation(pushRightIn);
                    vf.setOutAnimation(pushLeftOut);
                    // right to left swipe
                }

                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > REL_SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > REL_SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
                    vf.setInAnimation(pushLeftIn);
                    vf.setOutAnimation(pushRightOut);
                    // left to right swipe
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```